# How to create records from XML files for all existing companies on module install

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

How do I create records from XML files for all existing companies on module install, lets say I have a :

```
<record id='something' model='hr.things'>
   <field name='name'>Something nice.</field>
   <field name='company_id' eval="False"></field>
</record>
```

and I have 3 companies: Google, Facebook and Yahoo...

I want to have **'Something nice.'** for the three companies on module install.